# Concurrent Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having issues getting 3 threads to run concurrently.  I would like to have the "trade" loop, the "prices"loop and the "stop" loop run at the same time however it seems that the "stop" loop hijacks the program and runs while the others wait their turn.  How should I set it up so that they all run at the same time?

```
import Queue
import threading
import time
import json

from execution import Execution
from settings import STREAM_DOMAIN, API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID
from strategy import TestRandomStrategy
from streaming import StreamingForexPrices
from event import TickEvent
from rates import stop



def trade(events, strategy, execution):
    """
    Carries out an infinite while loop that polls the
    events queue and directs each event to either the
    strategy component of the execution handler. The
    loop will then pause for "heartbeat" seconds and
    continue.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            event = events.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if event is not None:
                if event.type == 'TICK':
                    strategy.calculate_signals(event)
                elif event.type == 'ORDER':
                    print "Executing order!"
                    execution.execute_order(event)
        time.sleep(heartbeat)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat = 0  # Half a second between polling
    events = Queue.Queue()

    # Trade 1000 unit of EUR/USD
    instrument = "EUR_USD"
    units = 1
    stopLoss = stopper




    # Create the OANDA market price streaming class
    # making sure to provide authentication commands
    prices = StreamingForexPrices(
        STREAM_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID,
        instrument, events
    )
    #handle stopLoss price
    stopper = stop()

    # Create the execution handler making sure to
    # provide authentication commands
    execution = Execution(API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID)

    # Create the strategy/signal generator, passing the
    # instrument, quantity of units and the events queue
    strategy = TestRandomStrategy(instrument, units, events, stopLoss)

    # Create two separate threads: One for the trading loop
    # and another for the market price streaming class
    trade_thread = threading.Thread(target=trade, args=(events, strategy, execution))
    price_thread = threading.Thread(target=prices.stream_to_queue, args=[])
    rate_thread = threading.Thread(target=stop, args=[])

    # Start both threads
    trade_thread.start()
    price_thread.start()
    rate_thread.start()
```

Just fyi, everything worked great until I tried to add the "rate".  The only things I have added are an additional thread, the stopLoss and the rate.py file.

rate.py:

```
import oandapy
import time
oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxxxxx")


while True:
    response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
    prices = response.get("prices")
    asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
    stop = asking_price - .001
    print stop
    time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a remark:

- don't use `sleep` if you can avoid it; for example, in the "trade" loop you
  don't need sleep at all if you make a blocking `.get()` on your queue

Then, once the "rates.py" is imported it starts the `while` loop; you're
missing the `stop()` function (or your code is not complete ?)

*EDIT:* in case you want to add the `stop` function in rates.py, just put
the `while` loop code inside a `def stop():` block like this

```
def stop():
    while True:
        response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
        prices = response.get("prices")
        asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
        stop = asking_price - .001
        print stop
        time.sleep(1)
```

(btw: do you really know what you're doing?)

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  I'll see if I can get it going correctly.  One question, is using sleep causing the issues with simultaneous threads?

Comment: No it's probably not causing the issue with multiple threads, but it slows down the processing - a blocking get wait until something arrives in the queue, so without the sleep you're processing more events, faster

Comment: I think you are right about my code not being complete as well.  How would I add the stop() function into this scenario?